# Magento: create static block from Product Filter

Tags: layout, blocks, layered-navigation, static-block, ce-1.9.2.2

I want to create a static block of the default Magento Filterable Product Attributes, like in the picture below.
The problem is not in creating the static block.
What I don't know is how to have the Product Filter showing up in that block in a way that I can add the block to any page I want..

Is this possible or does the Product Filter only show up when there are products on that particular page?

I am using Magento 1.9.2.2 with the standard rwd template.

[image: block with Filterable Product Attributes.]

Comment: I don't understand your question. What are you trying to do? Where do you want this block to appear? Which Magento version are you working on? Do you use a custom theme? Please explain in greater detail and maybe add screen shots showing your problem.

Comment: @ForMat: See the picture. I want the "SHOP BY" block on my home page and any other page. I thought that should be possible by using a static block that contains the "SHOP BY" logic.

Comment: A "static block" is by definition just that: static.

Comment: @benmarks I remember I used to call a phtml file via a widget in a static block. So in that respect it's not completely static, is it.

Answer (score 2):

Several options.
**First:** product specific by adding Custom Layout Update on any product page.
For instance:

```
<!-- LAYERED NAVIGATION in left column-->
<reference name="left">
<!-- Layered Navigation Block -->
    <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml">
    <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers"/>
    </block>
</reference>
```

**Second:** use local.xml to trigger the layered navigation block appear on selected types of pages.

```
<!-- LAYERED NAVIGATION in left column-->
<default>
    <reference name="left">
    <!-- Layered Navigation Block -->
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml" >
        <block type="core/text_list" name="catalog.leftnav.state.renderers" as="state_renderers" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```